# Scaling vector images in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vector-graphics

Let's suppose, that we have the following vector image consisting of two paths:

```
<Path Data="M 0 0 L 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 8 Z" Fill="Black" />
<Path Data="M 4 0 L 8 0 L 8 8 L 4 8 Z" Fill="Black" />
```

The most important fact is, that this image is supposed to be 16x16 units (despite fact, that only 8x8 square area is covered by the actual image).

I want the image to scale to desired size - for example, I want to place it somewhere with size 32x32 (then, the drawn square should be of 16x16 size). How can I do it?

The even harder part is, that I want the image to reside in the resources. This can be solved in the following way:

```
<Canvas Width="16" Height="16" x:Key="MyImage">
    <Path Data="M 0 0 L 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 8 Z" Fill="Black" />
    <Path Data="M 4 0 L 8 0 L 8 8 L 4 8 Z" Fill="Black" />
</Canvas>

(...)

<ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource MyImage}" />
```

But that doesn't solve the problem with scaling. If it is possible, I would like a solution not involving usage of various `Transform`s.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use transforms? That would seem to be the logical solution.

Comment: Generally the whole point of the image being vector is that I don't have to apply transforms for the image to scale. I'd like simply put it inside container of desired size and watch it scale nicely :) But if there is no other way, I suppose, I'll use transforms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to resize nicely to any size, place it in a `Viewbox` with `Stretch="Fill"`.

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill" x:Key="MyImage">
    <Canvas Width="16" Height="16">
        <Path Data="M 0 0 L 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 8 Z" Fill="Black" />
        <Path Data="M 4 0 L 8 0 L 8 8 L 4 8 Z" Fill="Black" />
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

This will stretch the content to whatever the size of the `Viewbox` is.

If you want different stretching behaviour: [System.Windows.Media.Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch.aspx)

Comment: KaXaml reports: `A DynamicResourceExtension cannot be set on the Child property of type Viewbox. A DynamicResourceExtension can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject`

Comment: Unfortunately no, because the image is chosen basing on theme. When theme changes, another ResourceDictionary is loaded with some other image.

Comment: Try placing the Viewbox itself in the resources, with the content inline, then referring to it where your image belongs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you might have the wrong impression about vector graphics in WPF. While it is true that because WPF utilises vector graphics, it can smoothly scale these graphics, it should be noted that they *do not scale themselves*.

Therefore, you have [*a list of instructions that describe how to recreate an image using graphics primitives*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#visual_rendering_behavior) in your `Path` object, but it holds no resizing abilities. For resizing duties, you have two options: Use a `ScaleTransform`, or use a `ViewBox` (from the linked page on MSDN):

```
<Path Data="M10,100 C 60,0 100,200 150,100 z" 
    Fill="{StaticResource linearGradientBackground}"
    Stroke="Black"
    StrokeThickness="2">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="3.0" ScaleY="3.0" />
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>

...

<ViewBox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Path Data="M10,100 C 60,0 100,200 150,100 z" 
        Fill="{StaticResource linearGradientBackground}"
        Stroke="Black"
        StrokeThickness="2">
    </Path>
</ViewBox>
```